# flask-login alternative for beginner

Tags: python, flask

I will do project with my class, so they are a bit new with python. In our web application we will need registration/authentication. I used flask-login for this stuff, but I didn't enjoy this. I think it is difficult to understand and this is not obvious. I want to display that python is very simple to the class. I want to avoid duplications with log in stuff, what can you suggest to use instead?

Comment: Usually stack overflow isnt used for these kinds of questions, but there are plenty of [web frameworks for python.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)

Comment: Although I love Flask for teaching a class how simple things are would it not be better to use Django? Or you could create a very simple login interface yourself. If it is for teaching I doubt you need all the security settings.

Comment: @Greg I like flask, I just don't like flask-login module.

Comment: @JoeDoherty I love how flask organized, and it is much simpler than Django(I can create my own MVC actually with flask, and my mates will understand that it is better) In Django they will ask why we need this MVC model. I just don't like this tricky flask-login module. I think yes, it would be better to write my own module for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know, there are no popular alternatives to Flask-Login, except writing your own one. If you plan to do this, [`flask.session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#sessions) is highly relevant, as is a part of the [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/views/#step-5-the-view-functions).

There's also Flask-Security, but that builds on top Flask-Login. I used neither of them.